# what is a good semi-automatic espresso machine for home?

Tags: espresso-machine

I used to own a coffee shop, and was a good barista for my shop and I really miss a nice cup of latte or mocha, would love to have a nice espresso machine at home that is semi-automatic with a steamer and takes coffee beans.

I prefer if it is on a low budget, la marzocco if possible, a cheap one that could be refurbished.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Multiple questions are sometimes allowed if they're very much related, but in this case they seem too different to be asked in the same Q&A.

Answer (score 1):

There are loads of [best espresso machine](https://www.coffeemachineking.com/best-home-espresso-makers/) buyers guides out there. 99% of them recommend the **Breville Barista Express**.

I'd prefer something with a little more manual intervention like the New Gaggia Classic to be honest.

Cheers